# Reactjs - Material UI- reduc form framework - grouped checkbox required validation error fixing to have at least one checkbox required

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image]

I am working on a react project and have built a form framework which wraps material ui, around the redux form.

** sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-banzai-re6l3

I am unsure how fix a bug - where if the grouped checkbox field is set as validate - to only have a required message appear under the group of checkboxes - then demand all checkboxes to be required.

Here is the current code base

```
//renderGroupedCheckboxes

import React from "react";
import { Field } from "redux-form";

import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import FormLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormLabel";
import FormGroup from "@material-ui/core/FormGroup";
//import FormHelperText from '@material-ui/core/FormHelperText';

import renderCheckboxField from "./renderCheckboxField";

const renderGroupedCheckboxes = (fields) => (
  <FormControl component="fieldset" fullWidth={true}>
    <FormLabel component="legend">{fields.label}</FormLabel>
    <FormGroup row>
      {fields.names.map((item, j) => {
        return (
          <Field
            key={j}
            name={item}
            component={renderCheckboxField}
            label={fields.options[j].label}
            onChange={function (e, newVal) {
              fields.onHandle(e.target.name, newVal);
            }}
          />
        );
      })}
    </FormGroup>
  </FormControl>
);

export default renderGroupedCheckboxes;
```

the individual checkbox

```
    //renderCheckboxField
    
    import React from "react";
    import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
    import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
    import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";
    import FormHelperText from "@material-ui/core/FormHelperText";
    
    const renderCheckboxField = ({
      input,
      rows,
      multiline,
      label,
      meta: { touched, error, warning }
    }) => (
      <FormControl component="fieldset">
        <FormControlLabel
          label={label}
          control={<Checkbox />}
          checked={input.value ? true : false}
          {...input}
        />
        <FormHelperText error={error && error.length > 0 ? true : false}>
          {(error && error.length > 0 ? error : null) ||
            (warning && warning.length > 0 ? warning : null)}
        </FormHelperText>
      </FormControl>
    );

export default renderCheckboxField;
```

Comment: So your problem is that only one checkbox should be required but currently all of them are?

Comment: no no --  if the field is set as a required field -- at least ONE checkbox MUST be selected. its like checkbox1 OR checkbox2 OR checkbox 3 is true -- valid

Comment: you don't want individual checkboxes feeling they are required if they haven't been selected -- and you'd want a groupfield message to pop up - if NO checkboxes are picked at all - and disappear if at LEAST one is picked

Comment: Requesting you to mark the answer which addressed the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify renderGroupedCheckboxes.js. We are checking if any of the checkbox is touched and all the checkboxes are having error, then render the error text

```
import React from "react";
import { Field } from "redux-form";

import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import FormLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormLabel";
import FormGroup from "@material-ui/core/FormGroup";
import FormHelperText from "@material-ui/core/FormHelperText";

import renderGroupedCheckboxField from "./renderGroupedCheckboxField";

const renderGroupedCheckboxes = (fields) => {
  let error = null;
  let isAnyFieldTouched = false;
  let isAllFieldsError = true;
  
  for (let name of fields.names) {
    //if touched is true for any one field, isAnyFieldTouched will
    //be true 
    isAnyFieldTouched = isAnyFieldTouched || fields[name].meta.touched;

    if (
      error === null &&
      fields[name].meta.error &&
      fields[name].meta.error.length > 0
    ) {
      error = fields[name].meta.error;
    }

    //if invalid is false for any one field, isAllFieldsError will
    //be false 
    isAllFieldsError = isAllFieldsError && fields[name].meta.invalid;
  }

  return (
    <FormControl component="fieldset" fullWidth={true}>
      <FormLabel component="legend">{fields.label}</FormLabel>
      <FormGroup row>
        {fields.names.map((item, j) => {
          return (
            <Field
              key={j}
              name={item}
              component={renderGroupedCheckboxField}
              label={fields.options[j].label}
              onChange={function (e, newVal) {
                fields.onHandle(e.target.name, newVal);
              }}
            />
          );
        })}
      </FormGroup>
        <FormHelperText error={error && error.length > 0 ? true : false}>
          {isAnyFieldTouched && isAllFieldsError && error && error.length > 0
            ? error
            : null}
        </FormHelperText>
    </FormControl>
  );
};

export default renderGroupedCheckboxes;
```

Create renderGroupedCheckboxField.js as below. The reason we are creating new file it to not impact current behavior of checkbox field.

```
import React from "react";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import FormControlLabel from "@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel";

const renderGroupedCheckboxField = ({
  input,
  rows,
  multiline,
  label,
  meta: { touched, error, warning }
}) => (
  <FormControl component="fieldset">
    <FormControlLabel
      label={label}
      control={<Checkbox />}
      checked={input.value ? true : false}
      {...input}
    />
  </FormControl>
);

export default renderGroupedCheckboxField;
```

sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-fast-f3i12?file=/src/_SharedFormComponents/renderGroupedCheckboxes.js

Comment: there is no sandbox for this?

Comment: I created a sandbox, but the SO rules mention it should not be external link. Please look at edit history

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-fast-f3i12?file=/src/_SharedFormComponents/renderGroupedCheckboxes.js is the link to sandbox

Comment: Well a sandbox is a proof of concept - along with the post -- the FormHelperText needs to be outside of the group - otherwise it will display inline

Comment: this is still an issue - in that although it looks like the error messages are displayed correct -- there is still errors being marked in the object so it will actually stop the form from being submitted  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67095650/redux-form-group-checkbox-fields-setting-error-of-children-meta

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understand the question correctly, however you could use something like [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-bash-kxj8m?file=/src/App.js) and invalidate the general label instead of putting "required" under each checkbox.

Comment: My belief is this -- you have a checkbox group -- and if the field is set to be required -- it means that the person MUST make at LEAST 1 choice -- so [  ]  [  ]  -- invalid - required -- [ ]  [x] -- valid

Comment: the form framework is BUILT -- its really really complicated - heart beat -- I need help modifying the exact codebase I sent over earlier  https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-driscoll-hcei4  -- its powered by a json blob

Comment: there is already FormHelperText parts -- but the problem is stopping an individual checkbox feeling its invalid because its not been selected.

Comment: Sorry, but why not use radio buttons?

Comment: Yes you CAN use radio buttons -- but we are talking about a grouped checkbox - where perhaps there is a required validation on it -- so if it is required - AT LEAST ONE checkbox is selected

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution here.

Let me first explained.

When you have `names` as an `Array` that mean its a group of inputs.

So after I have checked that, next I will have to see if at least one of the item in the group passed the validation.

After that I will have to make sure that the group is of type `CheckBox` or `RadioButton` because when they are then it make sense that at least only one of the item must be selected.

So I made a simple change to `validateHandler` and made that work.

look below and here is the edited version on [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-sunset-iwbld?file=/src/GenericForm/GenericForm.js:1537-3257)

```
validateHandler(values) {
    //console.log("values",values);
    //console.log("this.props.fields", this.props.fields);

    const errors = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < this.props.fields.length; ++i) {
      let field = this.props.fields[i];

      var passedValues = false;
      for (let j = 0; j < field.name.length; ++j) {
        let fieldName = field.name[j];
        if (field.validate !== undefined) {
          if (field.validate.includes("email")) {
            //email
            if (
              !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(
                values[fieldName]
              )
            ) {
              errors[fieldName] = "Invalid email address";
            }
          }

          if (field.validate.includes("minLength")) {
            //minLength
            if (
              values[fieldName] !== undefined &&
              values[fieldName].length < 3
            ) {
              errors[fieldName] = "Must be 3 characters or more";
            }
          }

          if (field.validate.includes("required")) {
            //required
            if (!values[fieldName] && typeof values[fieldName] !== "number") {
              errors[fieldName] = "Required";
            } else {
              passedValues = true;
            }
          }
        }
      }

      // when at least one value passed of the group
      if (passedValues && (field.type === "checkbox" || field.type === "radiobutton")
      ) {
        for (let j = 0; j < field.name.length; ++j) {
          var fieldName = field.name[j];
          if (errors[fieldName] !== null) delete errors[fieldName];
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: No that's not correct -- the required label on individual checkboxes should never be seen here -- we should only see ONE error field bound to the whole group -- so none selected ONE required label under the group -- -at least one gets selected -- the required label under the group goes away

Comment: My friend, I gave you an idea and also made it possible to solve the validation problem. Now there is other thing you have to make so that it will work as whole for you. You cant expect me to o the whole things for you right. Anyway this should help you figuring out the rest.

Comment: The bounty is to solve the problem properly. Not half baked

Comment: this is still an issue - in that although it looks like the error messages are displayed correct -- there is still errors being marked in the object so it will actually stop the form from being submitted  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67095650/redux-form-group-checkbox-fields-setting-error-of-children-meta